# Excel index match with a condition to choose a specific column in a 3d matrix (formula or VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two tables in Excel, one with categories and listings, and another with points based on the category and listing threshold. It goes as follows:

Categories table:

| ID | CATEGORY | LISTINGS | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | A | 56 |  |
| 002 | C | 120 |  |
| 003 | A | 4 |  |
| 004 | B | 98 |  |

Points table:

| Category | tier1 | tier2 | tier3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| Range | 1-30 | 31-90 | 91- |
| Points | 10 | 20 | 30 |
|  |  |  |  |
| B | Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| Range | 1-25 | 26-100 | 101- |
| Points | 10 | 20 | 30 |
|  |  |  |  |
| C | Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3 |
| Range | 1-40 | 41-80 | 81- |
| Points | 10 | 20 | 30 |

I started with an INDEX MATCH formula pointing at the points:

```
=INDEX(Points!A1:D11, MATCH(Categories!B2, Points!A1:A11, 0)+2)
```

--> the +2 is to get the points directly

I also though of evaluating the thresholds with this formula:

```
 =IF(Categories!C2 >= NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(Points!D3, FIND("-",Points!D3)-1)),Points!D4,  IF(Categories!C2 >=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(Points!C3, FIND("-",Points!C3)-1)),Points!C4, Points!B4))
```

I thought that the else if the if would make it faster.

Could someone help me populate the Points column in the Categories table? VBA code is also acceptable. The tables are in different sheets.

Comment: Can't you reformat the Points table to be like category-rangestart-rangeend- value- points? so you'd had a row for each category range and would make the lookup a lot easier

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There seems to be something wrong with the formatting of the points table in your question - could you edit it so we can read it better plz?

Answer (score 1):

José, your original Match formula is the right starting place. It locates the particular sub-table to do a further lookup on.  But in order to make this formula a whole lot simpler, can we change the ranges (1-30, 31-90, 91-) to have just their starting points (1, 31, 91)?  If we do that simple change then we can use the approximate lookup feature of HLookup to easily and compactly specify the Lookup:

```
=HLookup($C2,Offset(Points!$A$1,Match($B2,Points!$A:$A,0),1,2,3),2,True)
```

In the middle of this formula you can see your original Match function to locate the correct sub-table based on the category.  We need to feed that start point to OFFSET() to create a table range useful to the HLookup.  Offset takes an anchor cell reference (top left of the Points table), number of rows to count down from there (result of the Match), number of columns to the right (1), the number of rows in the range (2), and the number of columns in the range (3).

The Hlookup is just like a VLookup, but for tables arranged left-to-right not top-to-bottom.  The True as the last parameter is very important as it tells HLookup to use the range lookup instead of an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly verbose formula which takes the data as originally formatted (using Excel 365 Let):

```
=LET(ranges,INDEX(Points!B$2:D$12,MATCH(B2,Points!A$1:A$12,0),0),
leftRanges,VALUE(LEFT(ranges,FIND("-",ranges)-1)),
points,INDEX(Points!B$2:D$12,MATCH(B2,Points!A$1:A$12,0)+1,0),
INDEX(points,MATCH(C2,leftRanges)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it's urgent this is what I got but I cannot continue before tomorrow. Assuming you can at least put the tiers next to the category (A on same line as tiers) this will get you the first tier. You just need to copy the whole formula in the "nextCol", with minor modifications to get the next tiers.
if you really cannot change the source you need to add an additional offset in the first match.

```
=IF(AND(D1>NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,0)),FIND("-",INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,0)))-1)),D1<NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E1,A:A,0)),2))),INDEX(B:D,MATCH(E1,A:A,0)+1,1),"nextCol")
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Score()

   Dim wsP As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet, dict
   Dim iLastRow As Long, r As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
   Dim sCat As String, iListing As Integer
   Dim data, ar

   Set wsP = Sheets("Points")
   Set wsC = Sheets("Categories")
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

   iLastRow = wsC.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   data = wsC.Range("A1:D" & iLastRow).Value2
   
   ' category to row lookup
   For i = 1 To UBound(data)
      If data(i, 1) = "Range" Then
          dict.Add Trim(data(i - 1, 1)), i ' range
      End If
   Next
   
   ' scan points
   iLastRow = wsP.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   For r = 2 To iLastRow
       sCat = Trim(wsP.Cells(r, "B"))
       iListing = wsP.Cells(r, "C")
       If dict.exists(sCat) Then
           i = dict(sCat)
           For j = 4 To 2 Step -1
              ar = Split(data(i, j), "-") ' lower-upper limit
              If iListing >= ar(0) Then ' check lower limit
                  ' update points
                  wsP.Cells(r, "D") = data(i + 1, j) ' points
                  Exit For
              End If
           Next
       Else
          MsgBox "No match '" & sCat & "'", vbCritical, "ERROR row " & r
       End If
   Next
   MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It uses arrays and should be very fast, working only in memory. Please use your sheets when setting `shC` and `shP` as your real sheets. I only use the active sheet and the next one for testing reason:

```
Sub GetPoints()
 Dim shC As Worksheet, shP As Worksheet, lastRC As Long, lastRP As Long, arrBC, arrP, arrPP, arrFin
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, p As Long, k As Long
 
 Set shC = ActiveSheet 'use here your Categories sheet
 Set shP = shC.Next    'use here your Points sheet
 lastRC = shC.Range("A" & shC.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastRP = shP.Range("A" & shP.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arrBC = shC.Range("B2:C" & lastRC).Value  'put the range B:C in an array
 arrP = shP.Range("A2:D" & lastRP).Value   'put all the range in an array
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrBC), 1 To 1)  'redim the array to keep processed values
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrBC)       'iterate between Categ array elements:
        For j = 1 To UBound(arrP) 'iterate between Points array elements:
            If arrP(j, 1) = arrBC(i, 1) Then 'if Category is found:
                For p = 2 To 4               'iterate between the next array row elements
                    arrPP = Split(arrP(j + 1, p), "-") 'split the element by "-" to determine the interval
                    If arrPP(1) <> "" Then             'for the tier3 case:
                        If arrBC(i, 2) >= CLng(arrPP(0)) And arrBC(i, 2) <= CLng(arrPP(1)) Then
                            k = k + 1
                            arrFin(k, 1) = arrP(j + 2, p): j = j + 2: Exit For 'place the value in the final array and exit iteration
                        End If
                     Else                               'for the tier1 and tier2 cases:
                        If arrBC(i, 2) >= CLng(arrPP(0)) Then
                             k = k + 1
                            arrFin(k, 1) = arrP(j + 2, p): j = j + 2: Exit For 'place the value in the final array and exit iteration
                        End If
                     End If
                Next p
            End If
        Next j
 Next i
 'drop the final array result at once:
 shC.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```